# Homestead : only welcome route works

Tags: angularjs, laravel, homestead

I have a separate front end (Angular) in the folder 'client'.

In the folder 'server' I have a Laravel installation.

In my Homestead.yaml I map trivial.local to /Code/trivial (instead of /Code/trivial/public)

All works fine: Angular, Laravel, but ONLY with the welcome view.

Each other Laravel route gives : "No input file specified".

How can I fix this non-default mapping?

Comment: `/Code/trivial` contains the `client` and `server` directories? I don't understand how you get any view from Laravel from your description without a `/public` in the URI... I'm not sure why you wouldn't just put your angular app in `/public` and keep the standard homestead mapping.

Comment: Yes. http://trivial.local/server/public works (welcome). It's possible to put the dir 'client'in the 'public' and change the mapping. But I wish full separation. In xampp it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to have an separated API from your client, right?

The best approach in my opinion is to have two complete separated folders.

1. **/client** (Angular app)
2. **/server** (Laravel app)

Then your `Homestead.yaml` file would look like this:

```
sites:
- map: server.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/server/public
- map: client.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/client/public # or whatever your index.html is
```

To finish in your nginx configuration add `/index.html`

In order to do that, inside the vm run the following commands:

```
$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
$ sudo nano client.dev
```

Next find this line:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

And add the `index.html` to it like so:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.html  /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Now you just need to restart the service

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

And you are good to go.